# Music Note Flashcards

Tags: sight-reading

Beginner looking to improve music note recognition, particularly for bass clef and tenor clef (I'm proficient in treble). Any suggestions besides just slugging my way through music?

Unlike the other question, [Learning standard notation without succumbing to simply remembering songs?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9966/learning-standard-notation-without-succumbing-to-simply-remembering-songs), I am already proficient at treble clef, i.e. reading standard notation; I don't "simply remember songs," or rely on my ear. It's also 5 years 9 months old and maybe newermore info available? I thought the mnemonics idea and links below were helpful and neither mentioned in the other post. Not a big deal though. Thanks.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking for here. Are you wanting to recognise written score? If so, there really is no alternative to practicing, "slogging" your way through music.

Comment: Nothing beats doing it.  You simply need to get your head down and read as much music as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used these as mini assignments before (they have them for every clef) decent way to work on it reading away from your instrument. But the best way really is just reading though a bunch of music.

- [Free Bass Clef Flashcards](https://music-theory-practice.com/music-notes/bass-clef-flashcards.html) (music-theory-practice.com/music-notes/bass-clef-flashcards.html)
- [Tenor Clef Flashcards](https://music-theory-practice.com/music-notes/tenor-clef-flashcards.html) (music-theory-practice.com/music-notes/tenor-clef-flashcards.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use maybe "mnemonic"-s to improve your skill.

One example is my favourite: FACE. The name of the notes in the spaces of the treble cleff.

For bass (and if you want to some for treble):

**"Great Big Dogs Fight Animals." for the lines of bass.**

**"All Caretaker Eats Grocery." for the space of bass.**

https://www.mnemonic-device.com/music/

For tenor:

[image]

*(Image Source: http://whatbrassplayerswant.com/alto-and-tenor-clef-no-worries-with-these-simple-tricks/)*

**"Every Garage Band Dominates." for the spaces of tenor.**

**"Dearest Friends Always Care." for the lines of tenor.**

Now look at the alto cleff just to be sure:

[image]
*(Image Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clef)*

**"F A C E" for the lines of alto.**

**"Global Boredom Doesn't Fail." for the spaces.**

The last one doesn't make as much sense as the ones before but maybe help.